# JQuery slideUp/slideDown with simple FAQ - extra function running

Tags: jquery

I have a simple but fairly long FAQ page (so not requiring a complex JQueryUI accordion type script). I've set up as follows, repeating for each question/answer down the page:

```
<h3 class="faqoff">Question here</h3>
<div class="faqa">
    Answer here (can be lots of paras, lists, etc.)
</div>
```

I then have the following at the end of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $("div.faqa").hide();                           /* hide all div.faqa on page load */
 $("h3.faqoff").click(function () {              /* when 'faqoff' H3 (hidden answer) is clicked */
     $("div.faqa").slideUp(500);                    /* close any open div.faqa */
     $(this).toggleClass("faqoff faqon");           /* swap faqoff/faqon class for H3 */
     $(this).next("div.faqa").slideDown(500);       /* open the div.faqa for this H3 */
 });
 $("h3.faqon").click(function () {               /* when 'faqon' H3 (visible answer) is clicked */
     $(this).toggleClass("faqoff faqon");           /* swap faqon/faqoff class for H3 */
     $("div.faqa").slideUp(500);                    /* close the div.faqa for this H3 */
 });
</script>
```

This almost works, except that once an FAQ has been displayed (the H3 is now class .faqon and its div.faqa is visible), clicking on the H3 again slides the div.faqa up but then it slides down again, which as far as I can see is only in the function for .faqoff - have I missed something?  I get the same result in IE11 and latest Chrome.

New to jsfiddle but hopefully - http://jsfiddle.net/mDWt2/

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle and add it to the post?

Comment: `faqoff` what a great name, sounds like fu*koff ?

Comment: You now you have to close those comments, right ?

Comment: I should know about closing comments, they're not actually in my page, only here to explain what I was trying to do, oops!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handlers are attached to the elements matching the selector at execution time, changing the class later does nothing for the event handlers, they are still attached to the same elements

Try something like this

```
$("div.faqa").hide();
$("h3.faqoff").on('click', function () {
     var elem = $(this).next("div.faqa");
     $("div.faqa").not(elem).slideUp(500);
     $(this).toggleClass("faqoff faqon");
     elem.slideToggle(500);
 });
```

Comment: Understand the event handler explanation - thanks! However, won't the click function you've set out first hide all of the div.faqa then slide down (via toggle) the one for this H3? What I'm trying to do is have a slideUp for the current one if it's already open (which is why I thought about a second click function - I can now see why that won't work).

Comment: @Adam - That can easily be avoided, edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q9Ax5/1/) for your reference. Actually, you don't need to write too many lines of code and make things complicated. Have a look on jsfiddle and see for yourself. Here's the code anyways:

```
$('.a').filter(':nth-child(n+4)').hide();

$('.q').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next().slideDown(200)
    .siblings('.a').slideUp(200);
});
```

Also, It's good when you show the first answer by default. That's why I used .filter method to achieve that. 
Just in case, you want all answers to be hidden by default, then use:

```
$('.a').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks - much easier than my original; and I understand more about jsfiddle and siblings too!